# How does the Like operator behave with an empty argument (%%)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using the `like` operator

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM student_details WHERE first_name LIKE 'S%';
```

will provide the name which start with S.

But

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM student_details WHERE **first_name LIKE '%%';**
```

`%%` - It didn't have any string constraints. This query is returning the complete list.

How is `LIKE %%` processed in SQL?

Can anyone clarify this?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation of `like` ? Why would it not return the complete list ?

Answer (score 3):

The `%` sign is considered the zero-or-more repetition wildcard character in `SQL`. The way it works is pretty much the same as in any other areas of computing, you can have a wide definition and explaination of how it works just putting it in Google.

That's why it returns *all* the entries in your database, because it matches anything even if it isn't repeated a time (by the way, the same behavior you'll achieve with `LIKE '%'`).

The one and just one repetition wildcard in `SQL` is usually represented with `_`.

Answer (score 1):

If do not pass any search string then LIKE will return all values

You have to see this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Answer (score 0):

The % signifies zero or more occurences of whatever characters.

So `first_name like '%%'` (or `first_name like '%'` for that matter) will return all records where first_name contains zero or more characters. That means all records, except those where first_name is NULL.